# Meteor set overall template context

Tags: javascript, meteor

In meteor I can set various template helpers like this:

```
Template.story.title = function () {
  return "title";
};
<template name="story">
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  <p>{{description}}</p>
</template>
```

Which is great but, if I have a lot of variables I wouldn't want to set them individually, I want to pass the context to the main template.

How do I do that?

```
Template.story.data = function () {
  return {title:"title", description:"desc"};
};
<template name="story">
  <h3>{{title}}</h3>
  <p>{{description}}</p>
</template>
```

That doesn't work. THanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set the context of the template when you call it:

```
{{> story data}}

Template.outerTemplate.data = function() { 
  return {title:"title", description:"desc"};
}
```

Or you can just use `{{#with}}` to set the the template context on the fly:

```
{{#with data}}
  {{title}}
{{/with}}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are absolutely on the right way but missed to use your template variable the way you defined it. As `Template.story.data` is defined to return an object, you should use it like an object:

```
<template name="story">
  <h3>{{data.title}}</h3>
  <p>{{data.description}}</p>
</template>
```

Voilá. Of course every template variable can hold more than just a string.

Comment: Thanks this works but, shouldn't there be a way to set a main context? meteor docs says that `this` is the assumed context. There should be a way to set `this` instead of `data`. Thanks.