# Pass a template name as string to another template in Meteor/Handlebars

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js

I have a template that contains a second template, I'd like to make the second template variable ie. it can change depending on what I pass as the template name.

```
<template name="template1">
    <div>
        {{> template2}}
    </div>
</template>
```

So when my main page shows template1 I want to specify the template to use for template2.

```
<template name="main">
    {{> template1 TemplateArgs }}
</template>
```

I know how to set up TemplateArgs - it would contain the name of the template I want to use for template2.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A future version of meteor allows this with the new Meteor UI functionality. Currently you need to do this manually in a different way. See [Meteor set overall template context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13005890/meteor-set-overall-template-context).

#### Meteor UI

Beware meteor UI is still in a betaish and is a bit buggy. More details on the [post in the references](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/gHSSlyxifec)

If you use meteor UI (which you can use in preview mode with)

```
meteor --release template-engine-preview-5
```

Then you can do stuff like this

```
Template.main.template1 = function (value2) {
    return Template["template2"].withData({foo: "bar", value2: value2}));
}
```

Then html like

```
{{>template1 "valueofvalue2"}}
```

#### Current Version / Spark rendering

There is a way in the current version of meteor but it wont work with the UI release since `Meteor.render` will be phased out in favour of using DOM objects

```
Template.main.template1 = function(value2) {
    return Meteor.render(Template.template2({foo: "bar", value2: value2});
}
```

Then something like this in your html. You might have to play around with the data to get it working but its something like this

```
{{template1 "value2"}}
```

#### References:

- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/meteor-core/gHSSlyxifec
- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/New-Template-Engine-Preview
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aPf0LMQHIqk